# How to get a column from a multidimensional with deep key

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array which is multidimensional. I have to pull a specific key's value, but it is deep in the array. I'm trying to find the most efficient method to do this.

```php
$array = [
    [
        'price' => ['cost' => 200, 'tax' => 10, 'total' => 210],
        'otherKey' => 'etc'
    ],

    [
        'price' => ['cost' => 500, 'tax' => 50, 'total' => 550],
        'otherKey' => 'etc'
    ],
    [
        'price' => ['cost' => 600, 'tax' => 60, 'total' => 660],
        'otherKey' => 'etc'
    ],
];

// desired output is contents of "total" keys:
// [210, 550, 660]
```

I know this can be done by using nested calls to `array_column()` or with a basic `foreach` loop

```php
$result = array_column(array_column($array, 'price'), 'total');

// OR

$result = [];
foreach ($array as $value) {
    $result[] = $value['price']['total'];
}
```

But I was hoping there was some way to specify a nested key in `array_column()` like

```php
array_column($array, 'price.total');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`foreach` is better way to do that even you can do a benchmark for performance you can have idea.

Answer (score 2):

Another option which may be more ideal if:

1. the array structure gets a little too convoluted AND
2. as long as the key that you are trying to access is unique to the values that you are trying to target

is to use `array_walk_recursive()`.  It will only visit "leafnodes" so it spares you from needing to check if an element is an array or not.

When used in this fashion, the output will be a flattened array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/hATcK))

```
$totals = [];
array_walk_recursive(
    $array,
    function($leafNode, $key) use(&$totals) {
        if ($key === 'total') {
            $totals[] = $leafNode;
        }
    }
);
var_export($totals);
```

Otherwise nested `array_column()` calls will do. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/fGooW)

```
var_export(
    array_column(
        array_column(
            $array,
            'price'
        ),
        'total'
    )
);
```

Or array destructuring in a body-less `foreach()` [Demo](https://3v4l.org/M96N5)

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as ['price' => ['total' => $result[]]]);
var_export($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple `foreach` should do the job, you could also write a function which takes a string as input, splits it and retrieves the values from the array.