# How to use array_column for a 3rd level key?

Tags: php, youtube-api

I've been working with youtube api. The playlist item's structure is the following:

```
[{
    "publishedAt": datetime,
    "channelId": string,
    "title": string,
    "description": string,
    "thumbnails": {
      (key): {
        "url": string,
        "width": unsigned integer,
        "height": unsigned integer
      }
    },
    "channelTitle": string,
    "playlistId": string,
    "position": unsigned integer,
    "resourceId": {
      "kind": string,
      "videoId": string,
    }
  }]
```

For every item, I want to extract the videoId (that is inside the resourceId).
With a multidimensional array (field set), I can use array_column `array_column($array,'title')`  for example. How can I retrieve the videoId property?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get column from a multidimensional with nested key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46275040/how-to-get-column-from-a-multidimensional-with-nested-key)

Comment: @LuisMontoya yes, it does, but I want to know if it has a better approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see where you're coming from, unfortunately, PHP is not as elegant as Javascript, in JS you would just do:

```
const videoIds = data.map(item => item.resourceId.videoId);
```

If you don't want to do a foreach in PHP what you can do is:

```
$videoIds = array_map(function ($item) {
    return $item['resourceId']['videoId'];
}, $data);
```

Please notice that this approach does not have any benefit in terms of performance, at the end of the day we are just looping through all the items in the array.

Comment: You could use arrow function notation for the closure: _$videoIds = array_map(fn($item) => $item['resourceId']['videoId'], $arr);_